# How to get value in <span> element using xpath()?

Tags: python, scrapy

I used scrapy-python to get currency value 510,940 in  element:

```
<span class="price-amount">
    <span class="currency_symbol">₫</span>
    510,940
</span>
```

And my code:

```
item["price"] = response.xpath("//span[@class='price-amount']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: What do you want to have after the extraction? ‘510,940’? ‘₫’? ‘₫ 510,940’?

Comment: I want get 510 940 and when I used that code, it return empty []

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for `price` and `currency`:

```
>>> txt = """<span class="price-amount">
...     <span class="currency_symbol">₫</span>
...     510,940
... </span>"""
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.xpath('//span[@class="price-amount"]/span[@class="currency_symbol"]/following-sibling::text()').get()
u'\n    510,940\n'
>>> sel.xpath('//span[@class="price-amount"]/span[@class="currency_symbol"]/text()').get()
u'\u20ab'
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, I get `['\n    ', '\n    510,940\n']`.

If you want `510,940`, you can use:

- `re:test(., '\d')` to filter out strings not containing numbers
- `.get()` (or `.extract_first()` if you want to go old school) to extract a single item as a string, instead of a list of matching strings.
- `.strip()` to remove the surrounding space-like characters.

That is:

```py
response.xpath("//span[@class='price-amount']/text()[re:test(., '\d')]").get().strip()
```

Also, for price extraction you might to use a specialized library, such as [price-parser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/price-parser).